# How can I insert block content between page fields?

Tags: theming, 8, blocks

My page content type has two entity reference types that reference other content types.

- Hero
- Quotes

The hero displays at the top of the page and I want the Quotes at the bottom of the page.

In between these two pieces of content I have custom blocks and views that I wanted displayed. 
How can I have the Hero and the Quotes nodes below other custom content?

Answer (score 6):

#### Using Template files

You can create a template file .html.twig for your content type or specific node.

Download and enable [Twig tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module:

> Twig Tweak module provides a Twig extension with some useful functions
> and filters that can improve developer experience.

And then on your twig template put:

```
{{ content.field_refhero }}
<dd>{{ drupal_view('view_name', 'block_1') }}</dd>
<dd>{{ drupal_block('block_id') }}</dd>
{{ content.field_refquotes }}
```

---

Alternatively, you could use the following modules

#### [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds)

> Display Suite allows you to take full control over how your content is
> displayed using a drag and drop interface. Arrange your nodes, views,
> comments, user data etc. the way you want without having to work your
> way through dozens of template files.

#### [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels)

> The Panels module allows a site administrator to create customized
> layouts for multiple uses. At its core it is a drag and drop content
> manager that lets you visually design a layout and place content
> within that layout. Integration with other systems allows you to
> create nodes that use this, landing pages that use this, and even
> override system pages such as taxonomy and the node page so that you
> can customize the layout of your site with very fine grained
> permissions.

Answer (score 2):

The content is itself a block in Drupal 8.

You should be able to achieve what you want by creating a view to display the second entity reference.

In your content type, change the display settings so the Quotes field is not visible.

Now create a new Block view. Set it to display the Quotes field, and under Advanced add a Contextual Filter for the Node ID, and select a default value of Content ID from URL.

Now you can display this block below your other blocks, and it will display the quotes for the current node.